# Check if Matplotlib artists with labels exist in figure?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to test if `artists` with `labels` exist in a `Matplotlib` figure?

For example:

```
if fig.axes.artist.__contains__('label') == False:
     print('no labels')
```

Or an indirect approach:

```
if len(fig.axes.artist.label) == 0:
     print('no labels')
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if my post below doesn't answer your question?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
labels_in_fig = True
for ax in fig.axes:
    if not ax.get_legend_handles_labels() == ([], []) : break
else:
    labels_in_fig = False
```